# @IBDesignable class's property not initialized

Tags: swift, ibdesignable

I have a IBDesignable class.

```
@IBDesignable
class Foobar: UIView {

    // ignore all init code

    var foo: CGFloat = 12

    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
         // use property foo to draw something
    }

}
```

What stranges me is that, when `drawRect` called, `foo` is `0`, so the view displayed in XCode is wrong. I can assign value to `foo` in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` to fix this problem. What I don't know is what caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark foo as `@IBInspectable`